# How to set C++ environment variable in Linux ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, environment-variables

I just installed Ubuntu on my Virtualbox on Windows.

I was trying to install cmake and the installation guide in the cmake website asked me to do the following steps

```
./bootstrap
make
make install
```

But when I just did the `./bootstrap` command I get the following list of errors, can anyone suggest me how I can set the C++ compiler on my system. As I just installed Ubuntu perhaps the C++ is not set currently.

Kindly help.

---

```
CMake 2.8.1, Copyright 2000-2009 Kitware, Inc.
C compiler on this system is: cc

Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C++ compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CXX.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.

Log of errors: /home/vikboy/Downloads/cmake-2.8.1/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
```

Comment: Why not install `cmake` via Synaptic?

Comment: if it does not find it looking in std location, likely it is because it is not installed and setting CXX won't help. But fyi,
`CXX=/path/to/compiler/g++` and then
`export CXX`
should be enough; in your case, installing the compiler should fix the problem... (build-essential, see the answer)

Comment: Hi ShinTakezou, I did sudo apt-get install build-essential and I could build the cmake and eventually use to build the OpenCV as well. Thanks.

Comment: @ShinTakezou, did you try `sudo apt-get install cmake`?

Comment: @Caspin it's not my problem; I am happy with people that want to install from source, anyway, at least until the package is "small" (hard times compiling openoffice and gcc, discontinued efforts). I've not a debian based distro so `apt-get` won't help, but of course can help the OP if s/he has e.g. Ubuntu or alike, as I imagine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install the `build-essential` packages via apt.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Hi Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I did sudo apt-get install build-essential and I could build the cmake and eventually use to build the OpenCV as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem.  Even I defined the CXX environmental variable correctly.

$CXX --version
g++ (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I looked at the log file of the ./configure output:
Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log

```
class NeedCXX
{
public:
  NeedCXX() { this->Foo = 1; }
  int GetFoo() { return this->Foo; }
private:
  int Foo;
};
int main()
{
  NeedCXX c;
#ifdef TEST3
  cout << c.GetFoo() << endl;
#else
  std::cout << c.GetFoo() << std::endl;
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

---

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Test failed to compile
Try: /usr/local/bin/g++
Line: /usr/local/bin/g++  -DTEST2 cmake_bootstrap_18998_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_18998_test
----------  file   -----------------------

The main problem is that the programmer who wrote the test did not include the
include path -L/PATH/to/C++/header, that on my computer is 
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0

This path should be included in the auto probing or should be an option in the configure program.  I hope the cmake developers can see this message and change the auto detect a little bit.

Or I may be wrong.