# Unable to upgrade cmake from 2.6 to higher

Tags: gcc, cmake, centos6

I am using centos 6.5 which has a cmake 2.6.
I want to upgrade to higher version (cmake 2.8 or cmake 3.0). 
I have the downloaded the setup files.
When i run the file using ./configure i get the following error message

```
[root@dtl-sameet cmake-3.0.0]# ./configure 
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.0.0, Copyright 2000-2014 Kitware, Inc.
C compiler on this system is: gcc 
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C++ compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CXX.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /home/sameet/Downloads/cmake-3.0.0/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
```

I have updated the gcc to higher version and i want to keep this higher version

```
[root@dtl-sameet cmake-3.0.0]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@dtl-sameet cmake-3.0.0]# g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040750/how-to-set-c-environment-variable-in-linux-ubuntu) answers the similar question but i did not wanted to install "Development Tools" as this would make gcc fall back to old version.

This [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1458464) answers the similar question but i did not wanted install a package manager.

I set the environmental variable for CXX as

```
export CXX="/usr/bin/gcc"
```

It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log`.

The configure script runs a number of tests. I assume that one of them failed.

You need to find out which one, what the test does and how to make it work or disable it.

You might want to update your question and hopefully someone will find out what is wrong with the cmake bootstrap on your system.

Comment: Re-installing the gcc, g++ and c++ solved the issue. I think the issue  was due to environmental variables not being properly set. Anyways thanks,